# How suitable is a glass pot for making Turkish Coffee with milk?

Tags: brewing-process, equipment, cleaning, milk, turkish-coffee

I'm looking into Turkish Coffee and it looks very appealing from a flavor, caffeine strength. and cleanup perspective.

I was considering one of the electric machines to boil, but it kinda seems like they have a very short and harsh boil.  So now I'm more leaning towards just a little pot.  Now, the shape of the pot seems to matter.  From what I can tell a small diameter will help to keep the sediment at the bottom.  But what is the purpose of the neck?  To control the boiling and prevent spills?

For material, I like the copper but am now leaning towards just a little glass pot shaped as the traditional Turkish Coffee pots are.

I'd be interested to hear how glass works in this regard.

Particularly as I intend to make my coffee with milk rather than water.  My concern being that cleaning a delicate glass container of milk products sounds unfeasible.  So it would have to be metal for milk?