# How to brew a Turkish style coffee with milk from a microwave?

Tags: brewing-process, equipment, turkish-coffee, temperature, chemistry

In my [further learning](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/q/6334/14157) about Turkish Coffee, I came across:
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVdpS7Xw69g

This looks quite intriguing.  Now, I do like milk in my coffee.  And a bit of coffee, as they say, in my sugar.  So that might complicate matters.

What would be a good process to brew a Turkish style coffee with milk and sugar in the microwave?  It could very easily go very, very wrong!

Comment: I am not sure this is a good idea. The proteins in the milk will quickly cause overflowing.

Comment: I think with the right artificial intelligence it would be awesome.  But in a dumb microwave?  yeh, probably a recipe for disaster.